# Configure Schemacrawler docker via configuration file?

Tags: docker, schemacrawler

Schemacrawler makes reference to a "configuration file", e.g. in https://www.schemacrawler.com/diagramming.html it says:

> Show column ordinals, by setting configuration option `schemacrawler.format.show_ordinal_numbers=true` in the configuration file.

But I've not found **what** and **where** that file is.

I run Schemacrawler from its provided Docker images and struggle to make sense of where to configure e.g. `schemacrawler.format.show_ordinal_numbers=true` as referenced in the above docs.

Anyone know how this is intended to work?

(BTW I'm asking on SO because [their repository suggests to do so](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/README.md))

Answer (score 1):

Seems it makes use of this file: `config/schemacrawler.config.properties`.

From its Github repo I found these links:

- [Diagram Readme](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/38d4c3d1dc1db05ba72bebd5a396f3f50c908397/schemacrawler-distrib/src/examples/markdown/examples/diagram/diagram-readme.md)
- [Sample config file](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/fac7b4045d8c65e89c93c7648dd42e083e853a58/schemacrawler-docs/config/schemacrawler.config.properties)

Comment: Thank you! That's useful, I hadn't found those resources. But still haven't made it work.. I've wrapped the image in my own Dockerfile and added `COPY schemacrawler.config.properties config/schemacrawler.config.properties`, and verified the file is there. It all looks correct but the file does not appear to be read. Hmmm...

Comment: Are you making the destination path of the `COPY` instruction correct?

Comment: Well, I think so: https://gist.github.com/gaggle/0b23d9e2c67698cb962ee174e183ed3a. I see the file in the image, and it is colocated with another preexisting config file dealing with color-mapping. But I don't see any differences in the output, I'm expecting DPI and Color settings to later the final output.

Comment: Please enter an issue on https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler and I will take a look

Comment: The file is NOT read automatically. You need to add `-g` option as mentioned by @SualehFatehi BTW it's a shame that the how to doesn't mention such basic things and doesn't provide example commands https://www.schemacrawler.com/how-to.html#excluded-tables

Answer (score 1):

Jon,

Please use the latest [SchemaCrawler Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/schemacrawler/schemacrawler/). When you open a shell in this Docker container, you will have a `schemacrawler.config.properties` file in the home directory. You can edit this file in vi, and then use it with SchemaCrawler by providing an additional `-g ./schemacrawler.config.properties` command-line switch. Instructions are provided on [the Docker Hub SchemaCrawler page](https://hub.docker.com/r/schemacrawler/schemacrawler/).

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.SchemaCrawler.com)